# Is there a way to derive the version of a dacpac without publishing it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Just as the title states, I need to be able to programatically validate the version of a dacpac prior to publishing it to a database. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with AssemblyInfo:

1. if it doesn't already exist; Create `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`. Make sure it's included in the project and contains at least this code:

```
using System.Reflection; 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] // Define however you want your version to be
```

2. Edit the `*.sqlproj` file in an outside editor (notepad etc) and add the following XML:

```xml
    <Target Name="SetDacVersionToAssemblyVersion" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(IntermediateTargetFullFileName)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" PropertyName="IntermediateTargetAssembly" />
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <DacVersion>$(IntermediateTargetAssembly.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1])
            </DacVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="DacVersion set to $(DacVersion)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
```

3. Get the AssemblyVersion with PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dacpac -Recurse | Select-Object Name,@{n='FileVersion';e={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}},@{n='AssemblyVersion';e={[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version}}
```